# AngularJS calling a method when its get new data in localStorage

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS localstorage and i injected this very well but problem in code.

I want when localstorage gets new data, so that its call a function `$scope.getAllContact()` automatically.

I am trying to solve this issue coz, for example, i opened two tab in browser, if i change anything in one tab, the latest change should reflect in other tab too without any reload and refresh.

At first see my code:

```
app.controller('crudCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {

  $scope.getAllContact = function() {
    var data = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data;
      // show something if success
    }, function(response) {
      //show something error
    });
  };
  $scope.getAllContact();

  // below method will post data
  $scope.formModel = {}; 
  $scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response) {

        $localStorage.name = response.data;
        $timeout(function() {

          $scope.successPost = '';
        }, 4000);
        //below $scope will push data in client site if the request is success
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
        //if any error occurs, below function will execute
      }, function(response) {
        // do nothing for now
      });
  };
});
```

above in `$scope.onSubmit()` methond, i send the submitted data to localstorage too, so i need if localstorage gets new data, it should execute `$scope.getAllContact()` always automatically without any refresh.

Can anyone fix me this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event:

```
 angular.element(window).on("storage", $scope.getAllContact);

 $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
     angular.element(window).off("storage", $scope.getAllContact);
 });
```

For information, see

- [MDN Window API Reference - storage_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)
- [MDN Web API Reference - StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent)